# Issue binding datagridview to a different datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview bound to a datatable and it works great. However, when I try to programmatically change the datasource property to a different existing table, I get a blank datagridview with no cells. Although I have tried many bits of code to remedy the problem, this is the one that I felt should do the trick:

```
dgvThresholds.DataSource = SquirrelDataSet.Tables("Threshold market 12")
ThresholdMarketTableListTableAdapter.Update(SquirrelDataSet.Tables("Threshold market 12"))
dgvThresholds.DataSource = ThresholdMarketDefaultBindingSource
dgvThresholds.Refresh()
```

Any advice on how to get this thing to work? Seems simple...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dgvThresholds.DataSource = SquirrelDataSet.Tables("Threshold market 12")
ThresholdMarketTableListTableAdapter.Update(SquirrelDataSet.Tables("Threshold market 12"))
dgvThresholds.Columns.Clear()
dgvThresholds.DataSource = ThresholdMarketDefaultBindingSource
dgvThresholds.AutoGenerateColumns = True
dgvThresholds.Refresh()
```

Comment: I still get a grayed-out datagridview.

Comment: What data type is `ThresholdMarketDefaultBindingSource` at the point of binding?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by data type of the binding source. If you mean what data type is it binding to, there are four columns consisting of 2 string fields and 2 decimal fields.

Comment: To put it another way: Is `ThresholdMarketDefaultBindingSource` a DataTable?

Comment: No, it is a binding source attached to a table.

Comment: I eliminated that line and I still have the same issue. It seems that setting the datasource property to the table should work, so I am totally lost here.